# client id mode on 2 identical id's

Tags: asp.net

I have an control1.ascx page
and control2.ascx page
both of them have this element:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_name" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

page.aspx contains both of the controls.

so now the page contains input type text with the id "txt_name" X2.

I am wondering how it is working? can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you want to use `ClientIDMode="Static"` only if you are sure that no other control has same name in the page.

For example, you really want to access the ServerControl from external javascript file (althought it is not a good design).

***If you are not sure, you want to use [Predictable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx).***

Answer (score 0):

As your are using `ClientIDMode="Static"` thus control's id will be rendered exactly as it is.

ID will be rendered directly. See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this [Blog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/May/04/Whats-New-in-ASPNET-40-Part-Two-WebForms-and-Visual-Studio-Enhancements) is a good read.

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.Net 4+** supports various modes to generate ClientIDs for controls.

Here is a reference for MSDN on ClientID and its' generation modes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.100).aspx

**To see how ClientID generation works, you may want to refer to this link :**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108887/Client-Ids-Generation-with-ASP-NET-4-0

(It has visual explanations on how the ClientID generation works in different cases)

Hope this helps.